# gwt: How to use setEventListener?

Tags: java, gwt

I have this code:

```
DOM.setEventListener(row.getElement(), new ClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(Widget sender) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }});
```

I think the code is fine and `ClickListener` extends `EventListener`, but it gives error saying: `The method setEventListener(Element, EventListener) in the type DOM is not applicable for the arguments (Element, new ClickListener(){})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer is that you probably don't. While this is available to attach listeners to events, you may only attach a single listener per element - that listen then gets all dom events that have been configured (see `DOM.sinkEvents`) - and you are responsible for making sure to detach all listeners before the page unloads, else some browsers will leak memory.

Instead, strongly consider using a Widget (and subclasses) to manage events. RootPanel, the base widget that others should be added to, will manage detaching all other widgets from the page to prevent memory leaks.

Additionally, you are able to listen to the events that happen within there based on the kind of event you are after. For example, even on a widget like a Label that doesnt' normally fire mouseover events, you can still attach handlers and get notification:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
    // do something
  }
}, MouseOverEvent.getType());
RootPanel.get().add(label);
```

In most cases, you'll be using existing support methods, like Button to get a click event - there are convinience methods already there for you, thanks to interfaces like `HasClickHandlers`:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    // do something
  }
});
panel.add(button);
```

More on GWT, Widget, and Memory leaks:

- https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dom_events_memory_leaks_and_you
- http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/UnderstandingMemoryLeaks

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! The reason I have to use DOM is because the handler definition is inside a loop which is also in 2 levels of anonymous object hierarchy (maybe I should not do this). The sender is a button inside a composite, which in the RootPanel, there are many of those composites so I used a loop to initialize them. But it keeps telling me my local variable is not final so I cannot get a reference to the outter object, even I used `OutterClass.this`. So I have to use DOM outside the hierarchy...

Comment: But yes I use widget to contain event handlers most of the time, and thanks for the hint on sinkEvent and memory leak!

Comment: You can do the following. Inside the loop declare a final variable and give it the value you want. for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ final int y = i; etc }. then you can use the y variable to referce it inside the handler definition.

Comment: @ThanosK. Final inside a loop is working! As a C developer I didn't expect this... Thanks!